# I'm not getting output for my palindrome program in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, palindrome, system.out

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        String A=sc.next();
        String B= "";
        /* Enter your code here. Print output to STDOUT. */
        for(i=A.length()-1;i<=0;i--){
        B = B+A.charAt(i);
        }

        if(A.equals(B)){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }


    }
}
```

I'm not getting the required output for my code. I'm a beginner in Java.

Comment: What output do you get for what input? And how are [concurrency] and [parallel-processing] involved?

Comment: for.... input : madam  Output : No

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what output you are getting and what output you are wanting.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program isn't giving you the desired output is because your for-loop is incorrect.

`for(i.A.length()-1; i <= 0; i--) {/.../}`

You are basically saying, whilst i is less than or equal to zero, execute the loop. i by default is greater than 0.

[image]

You can achieve a Palindrome check multiple ways. 2 Examples.

Example 1 using for-loop:

```
String A = "radar";
String B = "";

for(int i = A.length()-1; i >= 0; i -- ){
    B = B + A.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(A.equals(B) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Example 2 with StringBuilder.

```
String A = "radar";
StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder(A).reverse();

System.out.println(A.equals(B) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly getting an output of "No" because you're checking if i is less than or equal to zero on each loop, while you should be checking for greater than or equal to.

Change `for (i = A.length() - 1; i <= 0; i--)`

to

```
for (i = A.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop runs as long as the condition holds, in your case `i<=0`.
Unless the input has length 0 this condition never holds, thus the body of the for loop never gets executed and you immediately skip to `if(A.equals(B))...` which will always be `false` (except for the input `""`).
It should be `i>=0`.